# Java String.replaceAll() регулярное выражение заменить все спецсимволы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
        <div class="properties"> 
 <div class="properties__item"> 
  <div class="properties__header"> 
   <div class="properties__wrapper"> 
    <div class="properties__title"> 
     <div class="tooltip"> 
      <span class="tooltip__label">Мощность</span> 
     </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.properties__title --> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="properties__value">
                10 В
                </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="properties__item"> 
  <div class="properties__header"> 
   <div class="properties__wrapper"> 
    <div class="properties__title"> 
     <div class="tooltip"> 
      <span class="tooltip__label">Напряжение питания</span> 
     </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.properties__title --> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="properties__value">
                180-260 В
                </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="properties__item"> 
  <div class="properties__header"> 
   <div class="properties__wrapper"> 
    <div class="properties__title"> 
     <div class="tooltip"> 
      <span class="tooltip__label">Цвет свечения</span> 
     </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.properties__title --> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="properties__value">
                мягкий холодный
                </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="properties__item"> 
  <div class="properties__header"> 
   <div class="properties__wrapper"> 
    <div class="properties__title"> 
     <div class="tooltip"> 
      <span class="tooltip__label">Световой поток</span> 
     </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.properties__title --> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="properties__value">
                900 Лм
                </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="properties__item"> 
  <div class="properties__header"> 
   <div class="properties__wrapper"> 
    <div class="properties__title"> 
     <div class="tooltip"> 
      <span class="tooltip__label">Угол рассеивания</span> 
     </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.properties__title --> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="properties__value">
                120 °
  </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="properties__item"> 
  <div class="properties__header"> 
   <div class="properties__wrapper"> 
    <div class="properties__title"> 
     <div class="tooltip"> 
      <span class="tooltip__label">Индекс цветопередачи</span> 
     </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.properties__title --> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="properties__value">
                CRI&gt;80
                </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="properties__item"> 
  <div class="properties__header"> 
   <div class="properties__wrapper"> 
    <div class="properties__title"> 
     <div class="tooltip"> 
      <span class="tooltip__label">Степень защиты</span> 
     </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.properties__title --> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="properties__value">
                IP65
                </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="properties__item"> 
  <div class="properties__header"> 
   <div class="properties__wrapper"> 
    <div class="properties__title"> 
     <div class="tooltip"> 
      <span class="tooltip__label">Срок службы</span> 
     </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.properties__title --> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="properties__value">
                30000 ч
                </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="properties__item"> 
  <div class="properties__header"> 
   <div class="properties__wrapper"> 
    <div class="properties__title"> 
     <div class="tooltip"> 
      <span class="tooltip__label">Гарантий срок</span> 
     </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.properties__title --> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="properties__value">
                1 год
                </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

с этого всего нужно удалить все спецсимволы типа(`&gt;`) одним регулярным выражением для функции String.replaceAll()

UPD: это все нужно, чтобы сохранить в файл с форматом .csv

Comment: Тут же только один такой? `/&.*?;/g`

Comment: `&.*?;` так заработало

Comment: знаю регулярки, не знаю как работает данный метод в джаве xDDD

Comment: знаю, что в пхп нужно регулярное выражение в скобочки какие то запихивать, вот и тут пытался, а оно не работает

Comment: добавь текст как ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используем регулярку `&.+?;` для удаления:

```
String text = "  CRI&gt;80\n<div class=\"properties__value\">\n        CRI&gt;80\n  </div> \n </div> ";

text = text.replaceAll("&.+?;", "");
System.out.println(text);
```

Результат:

```
  CRI80
<div class="properties__value">
        CRI80
  </div> 
 </div>
```